# How to bind text to html select

Tags: jquery, asp.net

There are 2 dropdowns in the page and I'm trying to bind the same data to both of them. The data is received from an ajax call and is of type text/html.

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOne" runat="server" CssClass="ddlItems" >
  <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<select id="ddlTwo" runat="server" CssClass="ddlItems">
  <option value="0">Select</option>
</select>
```

**JS:**

```
function getData() {
 $.ajax({
            url: "/ShowMore.ashx",
            success: function (msg) {
              var result = msg.split(";");
              $(".ddlItems").html(result[3]);
            }
}
```

**ASHX:**

```
//some code

foreach (Type oitem in lstItems)
   {
     sbItems.Append("<option value=\"" + item.ItemId + "\">" + item.ItemName + "</option>");
   }
StringBuilder sbContent = new StringBuilder();
sbContent.Append("1;2;" + sbItems.ToString());
context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
context.Response.Write(sbContent);
```

result[3] is exactly like this:

```
<option value="1">ABC</option>
<option value="2">DEF</option>
```

The data is bound to ddlOne but not to ddlTwo. It is empty. No errors in console. What could be wrong here.

Comment: You have to get ajax data as JSON or something so you can iterate through each one and add as an option

Comment: how come it works for one of the dropdowns

Comment: If you use any functions of `jQuery` on selected elements which is meant to execute on an element, then it will execute it for the first element in that selected list. Example, in your case even if you have two elements with same class name, `.html()` will be executing on the first element in that list. You have to loop through the selected elements to apply for every element.

Comment: @Bharadwaj. I have commented ddlOne and checked. Still its the same

Comment: Usually, remove the code which you don't want from the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ddlTwo` the `CssClass="ddlItems"` should be `class="ddlItems"` like following.

```
<select id="ddlTwo" runat="server" class="ddlItems">
  <option value="0">Select</option>
</select>
```

Hope this will solve your problem.